# Xpath to find out element which has ANY text

Tags: xpath

I've situation where I can have text in any of the tags(not sure which one is that). Let's take following HTML code snippet for example:

```
<div .....>
  <div ......>
    <div ......>
       <div ......>
```

One of the above has text, but not sure which one has it. Let's take following two examples:

In this, div 3 has text:

```
<div .....>
  <div ......>
    <div ......>Hello
       <div ......>
```

In this, div 2 has text:

```
<div .....>
  <div ......>Hi
    <div ......>
       <div ......>
```

I want to get element for the div which contains ANY text, no matter what it is. Can we write xpath to get an element which has ANY text?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get all `<div>` having direct child non-empty text node(s) like this :

```
//div[normalize-space(text())]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the elements with blank text your selector should be like this

```
//div[. !='']
```

Here, `.` pointing to parent and `!=''` simply ignoring elements with blank text.

Answer (score 2):

and for any element you can use:

```
<div .....>
  <table .....>
    <tbody.....>
      <tr.....>
        <td.....>
          <span .....>Some text
            <div .....>

//*[normalize-space(text())]
```